# When app close and start again background service count loop run with its double speed

Tags: java, android, android-service

I implement a simple count program in background service class, it increment variable after one second.it also shows data in main activity after update service data with intent. But main issue is that when I close the app it still running in the background but when I start it again the counting speed increase mean to say variable value change 2 3 times within 1second. And if I start app about 1min after, value speed 10 to 20times fast. I don't know whats the issue is in program.

My Service Class

```
package com.darkcoderz.backgroundservices;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.JobIntentService;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

import java.util.logging.Handler;

public class BgService extends Service {

    int i=0;
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        showNotification();

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                while(i<1000)
                {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    i++;
                    sendData(i);
                }
                stopForeground(true);
                stopSelf();
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void sendData(int idata) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("donorrams");
    intent.putExtra("hello",idata);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void showNotification() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("donation","donation", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        Intent result = new Intent(this,BgService.class);
        PendingIntent pendresult = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,1,result,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"donation")
                .setContentTitle("DonorRams")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentText("We start processing on your donation")
                .setContentIntent(pendresult);

        Notification manager = builder.build();
        //manager.notify(999,builder.build());
        startForeground(123, manager);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
package com.darkcoderz.backgroundservices;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent service = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BgService.class);
        startService(service);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
                "donorrams");

        mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //extract our message from intent
                TextView count = findViewById(R.id.count);
                int msg_for_me = intent.getIntExtra("hello",0);
                //Toast.makeText(context, ""+msg_for_me, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                count.setText(""+msg_for_me);

            }
        };
        //registering our receiver
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        //unregister our receiver
        this.unregisterReceiver(this.mReceiver);
    }


}
```

Comment: Sounds like you are starting multiple instances of your service. That's what i'd look at

Comment: How can I fix this issue :(

Comment: Check if it's already running before starting it

Comment: It start when app start

Comment: You don't start multiple instances of your service, but you run several onStartCommands. Since you're starting a new Thread in your onStartCommand method, you may have running a couple of Threads executing the couting code snippet in parallel... The simplest solution would be keeping a thread reference in your Service class and checking every time onStartCommand is executed whether the thread reference is null (then start your thread) or if its not null, then the job might still be running...

Comment: @Tinsel Thanks that's the problem. If you figure out how to check if thread is running or not then its helpful for me because thread.isalive() not work for me

Comment: You could set the thread reference to null inside the threads runnable after your count down has ended. Then you only have to check whether the thread reference is null or not

Comment: @Tinsel null reference is not working. After while loop I added thread=null, but its not working. ```if(null != thread) {thread.start()} else{}``` it won't start thread even. it only execute else statement which is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
    private Thread thread;


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        ...
        if (thread == null) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    setThread(null);
                }
            });
            setThread(t);
            t.start();
        }
        ...
    }

    private synchronized void setThread(Thread thread) {
        this.thread = thread;
    }
```